# lwip.open doesn't work after mongoose findOne

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, multer

So I have mongoose, multer and lwip (they are required from the top part).

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var Users = require('../models/users.js');
var multer = require('multer');
var mime = require('mime');
var lwip = require('lwip');
```

If I comment the `Users.findOne` part, the image is cropped as I want it to be cropped. But if I uncomment it the `lwip` part stops working, though no errors are thrown. It just doesn't enter `lwip.open()`.

```
router.post('/image', upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {  

    //This part works always.
    Users.findOne({userid: req.body.userid}, function (err, user) {  
        var imgpath = req.file.path.split("public\\")[1];  
         user.user_photos.push(imgpath);  
         user.save(function (err) {  
             if (err)  
                 console.log('error');  
             else  
                 console.log('success');  
         });  
     });  

     //If I remove the top part, this part will work too.
     lwip.open(req.file.path, function(err, image){  
         image.batch()  
             .crop(200,200)  
             .writeFile(req.file.path, function(err) {  
                 if (err)  
                     console.log('error');  
                 else  
                     console.log('success');  
             });  
     }); 
});
```

You might need my multer config too, so here it is:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './public/uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var extension;
        if (mime.extension(file.mimetype) == "jpeg") {
            extension = "jpg";
        }
        else {
            extension = mime.extension(file.mimetype);
        }

        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + extension);
    }
});
```

Can you help me to figure out what the problem is here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both async functions. How can you guarantee both are done before the function exits? I recommend using a promise library like Bluebird. With it you can run multiple async functions at the same time and specify what happens when they both return.

Don't forget to 'promisify' any libraries that are used that you want to treat as promises. You're code will look something like:

my route('blah', function (){
    return Promise.all([ myfunct1, myfunct2], (retval) => { return {f1val: retval[1], f2val: retval[2]}})

I know some asshat is going to come along and take my answer and write out the code for you so that all you have to do is copy paste it, but I really do hope that you take the time to learn WHY and HOW  it works if you do not already know.

Comment: I was trying to use promises here, but didnt know I should use a library... Thanks...

Comment: No problem! Glad to be of help. If end up using promises and post other questions regarding how promises work feel free to mention me in a comment under your post and I'll give you pointers. Good luck!